# Upsampling daily multi indexed data to hourly samples in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe that looks similar to this:

```
                     time       currency          rate
2021-02-22 00:00:00+00:00            USD  54410.856295
2021-02-23 00:00:00+00:00            USD  48691.894832
2021-02-24 00:00:00+00:00            USD  49849.378714
2021-02-25 00:00:00+00:00            USD  46992.665450
2021-02-26 00:00:00+00:00            USD  46551.487477
2021-02-22 00:00:00+00:00            EUR  50410.856295
2021-02-23 00:00:00+00:00            EUR  41691.894832
2021-02-24 00:00:00+00:00            EUR  40849.378714
2021-02-25 00:00:00+00:00            EUR  42992.665450
2021-02-26 00:00:00+00:00            EUR  42551.487477
```

What I'd like to do is to upsample the daily data to hourly, so I have the hourly rate by currency. I've tried the following:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['time']))
df['time'] = df.resample('H').ffill()
```

But it fails because the column 'time' is not unique so I think I would need a multi index to do this. I've tried several things but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `time` as index, then `groupby`:

```
(df.set_index('time').groupby('currency')
   .apply(lambda x: x.resample('H').ffill())
   .reset_index('currency', drop=True)
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
                         time currency          rate
0   2021-02-22 00:00:00+00:00      EUR  50410.856295
1   2021-02-22 01:00:00+00:00      EUR  50410.856295
2   2021-02-22 02:00:00+00:00      EUR  50410.856295
3   2021-02-22 03:00:00+00:00      EUR  50410.856295
4   2021-02-22 04:00:00+00:00      EUR  50410.856295
..                        ...      ...           ...
189 2021-02-25 20:00:00+00:00      USD  46992.665450
190 2021-02-25 21:00:00+00:00      USD  46992.665450
191 2021-02-25 22:00:00+00:00      USD  46992.665450
192 2021-02-25 23:00:00+00:00      USD  46992.665450
193 2021-02-26 00:00:00+00:00      USD  46551.487477

[194 rows x 3 columns]
```